# Having trouble displaying the contents of my array stack

Tags: c, stack

So I am learning how stack works in C, and I wrote out a little menu that allows the user to push and pop integers to and from the stack. I used the global array implementation of stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5


int top = -1;
int myStack[MAX];

int push(int item){

    if(top >= MAX - 1){
        printf("stack overflow");
        return -999;
    }

    else{
        top++;
        myStack[top] = item;
    }
    return 1;
}

int pop(){

    if(top == -1){
        printf("no integer to pop from stack.");
        return -999;
    }

    int popped = myStack[top];
    top--;  

    return popped;
}

void displayStack(int myStack[], int top){
    for(int i = 0; i < top; i ++){
        printf("%d ", myStack[i]);
    }
}

int main(){


    printf("Menu Options:\n");
    printf("1 - Push\n");
    printf("2 - Pop\n\n");

    int data, choice;

    while(1){
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if(choice == 1){
            printf("Enter data to push: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            push(data);
            displayStack(myStack, top);
            printf("\n\n");
        }

        if(choice == 2){
            pop();
            displayStack(myStack, top);
            printf("\n\n");
        }

        if(choice == 3){
            break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

My problem is, when I run the code for the first time and insert 1 to push an integer to the stack, everytime, the first call to push, my display doesn't return anything. Only the second time will it display an item from the stack on the screen.
I think this has something to do with the indexes in my display function, but I'm pretty sure I have them correct? After I call push, the top of the stack for the first time goes from -1 to 0, and my displayStack function is starting at index 0.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Add `1` to `top` in the `choice == 1` block, like this: `displayStack(myStack, top+1);` First push, top is incremented to `0`. `0 < 0` is false on first call.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot! Are my return values appropriate in the functions where I reach stack overflow / underflow? I didn't really know what to return so I just returned -999.

Comment: To indicate a failure, I like to return `-1` like many system calls do. `-999` seems odd.

Comment: In `displayStack`, you need to change `i < top` to `i <= top` since `top` is the index of the top element and not the element count (although changing it to the element count would result in clearer code).

Comment: Oh that actually fixed it, I was confusing the top index with the element count yes. Thank you!

Comment: How would I change it so that it is clearer with the element count? Would I be using sizeof()?

Comment: @c_help123 No, just use 1 value higher than you are now.  Initialize it to 0, and use the original `i < top` in your loop etc. etc. - change all of the references to it (and rename it to something like `count`).

Comment: Since you don't use the return values of `push()` and `pop()`, you could as well define them as `void` functions.